# How to handle zero after decimal in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am reading an excel file using pandas function read_excel() function but pandas auto removed the .00 values from the data of dataframe.

Sample excel sheet Structure

```
Name    iteam   Price   Amount
qwe        2    20      40
dfg        1    23.00   34.01
rfe        0    0.00    0.00
```

Reading Above excel using below pandas function

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_excel(path,sheet_name="<Sheet_name>",header=None,dtype=object)
```

Reading every data as an **object** as that missing values will not affect datatype of dataframe.
DataFrame Created after executing the above line

```
index   Name    iteam   Price   Amount
  0      qwe      2       20    40
  1      dfg      1       23    34.01
  2      rfe      0        0    0
```

dataframe convert (0.00 to 0)and (23.00 to 23). Is there any way to restrict pandas from such conversions in dataframe?

Desired Dataframe structure

```
index   Name    iteam   Price   Amount
  0      qwe      2       20     40
  1      dfg      1       23.00  34.01
  2      rfe      0       0.00   0.00
```

Comment: what is issue if there is no `00`, if all are like `.00` then storing them in `int` will save some memory, if I am not wrong.

Comment: If need not objects and mixed `flaots` and `integers` it is not possible in pandas.

Comment: The values are identical. Do you worry about the display format? Why?

Comment: @Thomas Weller Basically Due to this auto slicing of .00 data type of cell changes from float to integer.

Comment: @Jezrael is it possible to handle only float and integer like the above scenario.

Comment: @Rishav - In pandas/ python not, maybe in some excel macro possible.